# Livewire Do Not Show The data Without the Page Reload

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Hi I am making a private chat application in Livewire but the thing is when I insert a message don't show unless I reload the page please help me how can i resolved that ? Thank you.

I am using Livewire Full-Page Components here is the Code

**The route**

```
Route::get('/messaging',Messaging::class)->name('messages');
```

**app\Http\Livewire\Messaging.php**

```
class Messaging extends Component
{
    public $body;
    public $searchTerm;
    public $selectedUser;

    public function mount(){

            $this->selectedUser =User::where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)
                                ->first();
    }

    public function render()
    {
            $searchTerm = '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%';
            if($searchTerm){
              $user=  User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('email', 'like', $searchTerm)
                ->with('messages')
                ->get();
            }

            $conservation = Message::query()
                ->where('sender_id',  Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('receiver_id',  $this->selectedUser->id)
                ->orWhere('receiver_id',  Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('sender_id', $this->selectedUser->id)
                ->with('sender')
                ->with('receiver')
                ->get();

    return view('livewire.messaging',[

             'users'         => $user,
             'conservation'  =>$conservation
        ]);
    }

    public function viewMessages($userId){

        $this->selectedUser = User::findorFail($userId);

    }

    public function sendMessages(){

        Message::create([
            'receiver_id'           =>   $this->selectedUser->id,
            'sender_id'             =>    Auth::user()->id,
            'body'                  =>      $this->body
        ]);

        $this->reset('body');

        $this->viewMessages($this->selectedUser->id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the render function after completing the calling method

```
public function sendMessages(){

    Message::create([
        'receiver_id'           =>   $this->selectedUser->id,
        'sender_id'             =>    Auth::user()->id,
        'body'                  =>      $this->body
    ]);

    $this->reset('body');

    $this->viewMessages($this->selectedUser->id);
    $this->render(); //this will load the all the conservation message 
}
```